# Modbus address PLC

Tags: serial-port, modbus, plc

Thanks a lot for reading this post and being able to help.

I would like to write a sigle coil in output Y5 of my PLC Panasonic FP.
I would like to know which modbus addres is output Y5.

In page 201 of Manual PLC https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/cps/rde/xbcr/pew_eu_en/mn_63489_0013_en_fpx.pdf there is a table which I think I can get that information from it but I do not know how represent it. (table attached)
[Table Modbus PLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoTMB.png)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output Y0 is at Modbus Address 000001, so output Y5 is at Modbus Address 000006.

For the first 14 output points on the Panasonic FP control unit, the Modbus address is one more than the output number.

Modbus addressing gets much trickier when trying to address outputs on the add-on cassettes or expansion units.

The link to the manual you posted appears to be dead at the moment (404), but I found [another manual online](http://sieuthitudong.com/App_Upload/Images/HM_FPX_v1.0_03.06.pdf) with some Modbus information starting at page 152 that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Panasonic PLC](http://panasonic-plc.com) is convenience if you need communicate with different brand by Modbus.